# Convert CST time zone to required Time zone Java

Tags: java, date, simpledateformat

I need to convert a Date which is in CST to required time zone. I will get Date as String like "11/5/2018 12:54:20" which is in CST time zone. I have to convert this to a time zone which is passed as a parameter. suppose lets take it as "GMT+0530".
The result for the above date ideally "Nov 06 2018 00:24:20"

I have tried the below code which returned the passed date(11/05/2018 12:54:20) as same instead of(Nov 06 2018 00:24:20) . I have executed this on a system which has IST time zone.

```
    SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm:ss");
    sdf.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("GMT-0600"));
    SimpleDateFormat sdf2 = new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm:ss");
    sdf.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("GMT+0530"));
    System.out.println(sdf2.format(sdf.parse("11/5/2018 12:54:20").getTime()));
```

**Edit:**
Answer:

```
    DateTimeFormatter f = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern( "M/d/uuuu HH:mm:ss" ) ;
    LocalDateTime ldt = LocalDateTime.parse( "11/5/2018 12:54:20" , f ) ;
    ZoneId z = ZoneId.of( "GMT-0600" ) ;
    ZonedDateTime zdt = ldt.atZone( z ) ;
    System.out.println(zdt);
    ZoneId zKolkata = ZoneId.of( "GMT+0530" ) ;
    ZonedDateTime zdtKolkata = zdt.withZoneSameInstant( zKolkata ) ;
    System.out.println(zdtKolkata);
```

Comment: @Andreas edited the question

Comment: Perhaps if you change the second `setTimeZone` call to `sdf2`, it'll do what you wanted. --- Also, remove the `getTime()` call. It's unnecessary.

Comment: @Andreas Its working. I overlooked that statement. Thanks a lot. You can reply so that i can accept it as answer

Comment: FYI, the terribly troublesome old date-time classes such as [`java.util.Date`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/Date.html), [`java.util.Calendar`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html), and `java.text.SimpleDateFormat` are now [legacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legacy_system), supplanted by the [*java.time*](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) classes built into Java 8 and later. See [*Tutorial* by Oracle](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html).

Comment: @BasilBourque Thank you for your information. Yes i tried the classes that you suggested. I will use this. thank you.

Comment: @Andreas has correctly identified what went wrong in your code. Allow me to suggest using better variable names: `sdfNewYork` and `sdfIndia` rather than 1 and 2 might have made it easier to spot the error (BTW I completely agree to use java.time rather than the old and troublesome `SimpleDateFormat` and friends).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## tl;dr

```
LocalDateTime                                            // Represent a date and a time-of-day, without offset nor zone. So *not* a moment, *not* a point on the timeline.
.parse( 
    "11/5/2018 12:54:20" , 
    DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern( "d/M/uuuu HH:mm:ss" )   // Define a formatting pattern to match your input string.
)                                                        // Returns a `LocalDateTime`.
.atZone(                                                 // Assign a time zone, to give meaning to the `LocalDateTime` object, making it a `ZonedDateTime` object.
    ZoneId.of( "America/New_York" )                      // Define a time zone properly with `Continent/Region` naming, never 2-4 letter pseudo-zones such as CST or IST.
)                                                        // Returns a `ZonedDateTime` object.
.withZoneSameInstant(                                    // Adjust from New York time to Kolkata time. Some moment, different wall-clock time.
    ZoneId.of( "Asia/Kolkata" )
)                                                        // Returns another `ZonedDateTime` object rather than altering (“mutating”) the original, per Immutable Objects pattern.
.toString()                                              // Generate text in standard ISO 8601 format, wisely extended to append the name of the time zone in square brackets.
```

> 2018-05-11T22:24:20+05:30[Asia/Kolkata]

## java.time

You are using terrible old classes, now supplanted by *java.time* classes.

Parse your input string as a `LocalDateTime` because it lacks any indication of offset-from-UTC or time zone.

Define a formatting pattern to match your input.

```
DateTimeFormatter f = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern( "d/M/uuuu HH:mm:ss" ) ;
LocalDateTime ldt = LocalDateTime.parse( "11/5/2018 12:54:20" , f ) ;
```

> ldt.toString(): 2018-05-11T12:54:20

You say this was intended for `CST`. Did you mean China Standard Time? Or Central Standard Time in North America?

Specify a [proper time zone name](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_tz_zones_by_name) in the format of `continent/region`, such as [`America/Montreal`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/America/Montreal), [`Africa/Casablanca`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Africa/Casablanca), or `Pacific/Auckland`. Never use the 2-4 letter abbreviation such as `CST` or `EST` or `IST` as they are *not* true time zones, not standardized, and not even unique(!).

I will assume you meant something like New York time.

```
ZoneId z = ZoneId.of( "America/New_York" ) ;
ZonedDateTime zdt = ldt.atZone( z ) ;
```

> zdt.toString(): 2018-05-11T12:54:20-04:00[America/New_York]

And apparently you want to see this same moment through the lens of the wall-clock time used by the people of a different region, a different time zone. By `IST` did you mean Irish Standard Time? Or India Standard Time? Again, use real time zones not these 2-4 character pseudo-zones.

```
ZoneId zKolkata = ZoneId.of( "Asia/Kolkata" ) ;
ZonedDateTime zdtKolkata = zdt.withZoneSameInstant( zKolkata ) ;
```

> zdtKolkata.toString(): 2018-05-11T22:24:20+05:30[Asia/Kolkata]

To see the same moment in UTC, extract a `Instant`.

```
Instant instant = zdtKolkata.toInstant() ;
```

> instant.toString(): 2018-05-11T16:54:20Z

All three of these ( `zdt`, `zdtKolkata`, `instant` ) all represent the same moment, the same point on the timeline.

In contrast, the `ldt` as a `LocalDateTime` object does *not* represent a moment, is *not* a point on the timeline. It held no real meaning until you assigned it a time zone to give it a context. Until assigning that zone, we do not know if meant noon hour in Australia or in Africa, or in America. It could have meant any of about 26-27 hours, the range of time zones around the globe.

## ISO 8601

Rather than inventing your own formats for exchanging date-time values as text, use the standard [ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) formats.

The *java.time* classes conveniently use [ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) formats by default when generating/parsing strings.

---

## About *java.time*

The [*java.time*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) framework is built into Java 8 and later. These classes supplant the troublesome old [legacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legacy_system) date-time classes such as [`java.util.Date`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/Date.html), [`Calendar`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html), & [`SimpleDateFormat`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html).

The [*Joda-Time*](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) project, now in [maintenance mode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maintenance_mode), advises migration to the [java.time](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) classes.

To learn more, see the [*Oracle Tutorial*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html). And search Stack Overflow for many examples and explanations. Specification is [JSR 310](https://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=310).

You may exchange *java.time* objects directly with your database. Use a [JDBC driver](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JDBC_driver) compliant with [JDBC 4.2](http://openjdk.java.net/jeps/170) or later. No need for strings, no need for `java.sql.*` classes.

Where to obtain the java.time classes?

- [**Java SE 8**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_8), [**Java SE 9**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_9), [**Java SE 10**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_10), [**Java SE 11**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_11), and later  - Part of the standard Java API with a bundled implementation.

  - Java 9 adds some minor features and fixes.
- [**Java SE 6**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_6) and [**Java SE 7**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_7)

  - Most of the *java.time* functionality is back-ported to Java 6 & 7 in [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/).
- [**Android**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Android_(operating_system))

  - Later versions of Android bundle implementations of the *java.time* classes.
  - For earlier Android (<26), the [***ThreeTenABP***](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP) project adapts [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/) (mentioned above). See [*How to use ThreeTenABP…*](http://stackoverflow.com/q/38922754/642706).

The [**ThreeTen-Extra**](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/) project extends java.time with additional classes. This project is a proving ground for possible future additions to java.time. You may find some useful classes here such as [`Interval`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/Interval.html), [`YearWeek`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/YearWeek.html), [`YearQuarter`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/YearQuarter.html), and [more](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/index.html).

Comment: Updated my question with your suggested answer. Please check

Comment: @user2390827 You needn’t do that. When you accepted this Answer, a big green checkmark is displayed for all others to see your choice.

Comment: @user2390827 You should never use a mere offset instead of a known time zone. An offset is merely a number of hours-minutes-seconds. A time zone is much more, a history of past, present, and future changes to the offset used by the people of a particular region. You are guessing what offset was in use in some place on some date at some time, but you may well be wrong. Let *java.time* track the zones and offsets, that’s its job.

Comment: @user2390827 And if you *do* need to use an offset when a time zone is not known, use the `ZoneOffset` and `OffsetDateTime` classes rather than `ZoneId` and `ZonedDateTime`.

Answer (score 0):

You are setting the timezone of `sdf` twice and not setting timezone of `sdf2` and thus getting incorrect results. Also, you don't need to call `getTime()` when passing object to `DateFormat::format()`.

Here is a fixed version of your code:

```
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm:ss");
TimeZone cstTimeZone = TimeZone.getTimeZone("CST");
sdf.setTimeZone(cstTimeZone);

SimpleDateFormat sdf2 = new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm:ss");
sdf2.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("GMT+0530"));
System.out.println(sdf2.format(sdf.parse("11/5/2018 12:54:20")));
```

Note that the classes you are using are quite old and since version 8, Java provides new [Date and Time APIs](https://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/java/jf14-date-time-2125367.html).

Comment: Correct answer.